# Show that, for $a<x<b$, the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is $F(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$

Tags: probability, self-study

We are given $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$ for $a<x<b$, and $0$ otherwise. My solution was
to integrate $f(x)$ such that: $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^bdx=\frac{1}{b-a}[x]_{a}^b=\frac{1}{b-a}[b-a]$. I think I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why have you integrated over the whole domain?

Comment: you calculated F(b)

Comment: So I integrate from $a$ to $x$? Can you give me some insight

Comment: Yes, although I'd change your notation slightly (inside the integral - see the proposed answer) to avoid ambiguity. Recall the definition of the CDF. You want to be able to evaluate it at any point in the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should integrate over $[a, x]$, not $[a, b]$:

$$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_a^x\frac{1}{b-a}dt=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^xdt=\left[\frac{t}{b-a}\right]_a^x=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$